# TreeView with ObservableCollection Source, no update

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I create a simple Treeview that I bound to an ObservableCollection.

```
ObservableCollection<IMarketDataViewModel> MarketDataItems;

public interface  IMarketDataViewModel
{
    string Title { get; }
    ObservableCollection<IMarketDataViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public MarketDataUserControl(IMarketDataViewer viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;
    marketDataTreeView.ItemsSource = viewModel.MarketDataItems;
}
```

When I update data in my ViewModel, I only see the first level in my Treeview. The only way I found to resolve the problem is to create an event in my ViewModel and when the data is updated instead calling PropertyChange on MarketDataItems, I trigger the event and the View reset marketDataTreeView.ItemsSource like this :

```
private void ViewModelOnOnUpdateItems()
{
   marketDataTreeView.ItemsSource = null;
   marketDataTreeView.ItemsSource = viewModel.MarketDataItems;
}
```

And this work perfectly --> All levels are displayed.

Someone know why the PropertyChange doesn't work and why I have to reset the ItemsSource ?

Comment: I thought binding should be done on properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue is that I didn't call OnPropertyChanged("Items")

```
public class MarketDataViewModelBase : IMarketDataViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    .....

    private ObservableCollection<IMarketDataViewModel> items;

    public ObservableCollection<IMarketDataViewModel> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items"); //Add this line fix my issue
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Would recommend making ObservableCollection properties get-only. Backed by a `readonly` field.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice.  But in for my issue as it's tree, initially only the root node exist with Items empty/null and all node are created after the binding with root is done

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement a binding to the `ItemSource` and this is done by a property:

```
// Create property
public ObservableCollection<IMarketDataViewModel> MarketDataItems { get; private set; }
...

// Create Binding
Binding bindingObject = new Binding("MarketDataItems");
bindingObject.Source = this; //codebehind class instance which has MarketDataItems
marketDataTreeView.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSource, bindingObject);
```

Or the binding in XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="marketDataTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MarketDataItems}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The problem was that I didn't call  OnPropertyChanged("Items")

Comment: @MohamedCHEROUATI yeah but it also had to be a property ;)